# Error while i try to install @tensorflow/tfjs-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

I try to install tensorflow/tfjs-node but got an error. I use windows. I can install tensorflow\tfjs but not tensorflow/tfjs-node. node v17.9.1, npm v 9.1.2. I try to install node gyp and windows-build-tools@4.0.0. Also i can install @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.8 but why i cant install latest version?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\img\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! CPU-windows-4.6.0.zip
npm ERR! https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-2.9.1.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@17.9.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\img\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8\tfjs_binding.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.6.0/CPU-windows-4.6.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.6.0/CPU-windows-4.6.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@4.6.0 and node@17.9.1 (node-v102 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.6.0/CPU-windows-4.6.0.zip
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.9.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.9.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.1 found at "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.3.32901.215) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "E:\vsc"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\WinUsers\\User\\Desktop\\img\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.9.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.9.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\User\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\17.9.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\WinUsers\\User\\Desktop\\img\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\WinUsers\\User\\Desktop\\img\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.9.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn E:\vsc\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `E:\vsc\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "E:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\WinUsers\\User\\Desktop\\img\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v8\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=D:\\WinUsers\\User\\Desktop\\img\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v8" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=8" 
"--node_napi_label=napi-v8"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\img\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.9.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'E:\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\img\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\img\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=8 --node_napi_label=napi-v8' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\img\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "E:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\WinUsers\\User\\Desktop\\img\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\img\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.9.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! * Downloading libtensorflow
npm ERR!
npm ERR! * Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
```

I try to remove node_modules, clear cache and remove package json

Comment: I suggest to install a more recent LTS node version (using `nvm`) and try again

Comment: no, i update my node to 20v, but got same error

Answer (score 0):

tfjs-node backend requires latest version of python, and latest version of Visual Studio with the workload for C++ Desktop Development installed